# I want this code to separate even and odd numbers

Tags: java, arrays

It prints all the even numbers, but is only printing the odd numbers 13 and 11. Not 3 or 5. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

public class ReadjustingArray {
    public static void main (String[]args){

```
    int[]A={13,3,4,6,8,5,10,11};
    int temp=0;

    for (int i=0; i< A.length; i++){

        if (A[i] % 2 ==0){
            temp=A[i];
            A[i-1] = A[i];
            temp=A[i];
            System.out.print(A[i] + " ");
        }

    }
    for (int j=0; j< A.length; j++){
        if (A[j] % 2 !=0){
            System.out.print(A[j] + " ");
        }
    }     
}
```

}

Comment: After your first loop completes, A looks like [13, 4, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 11]. What are you trying to accomplish in the first loop?

Comment: You also have a possible index error: if the first element of array `A` is modified to be an even number, the first condition will be true, and `A[i-1]` will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to modify the Array. Just print the odds in the same way you are printing the evens. Use their corresponding comparative logic.

Answer (score 2):

Don't modify the array with your first loop, then your second loop will work as you expect. Alternatively, in Java 8+, you might use `IntStream` and `filter` like

```
int[] A = { 13, 3, 4, 6, 8, 5, 10, 11 };
IntStream.of(A).filter(x -> x % 2 == 0)
        .forEachOrdered(x -> System.out.printf("%d ", x));
IntStream.of(A).filter(x -> x % 2 != 0)
        .forEachOrdered(x -> System.out.printf("%d ", x));
System.out.println(); // <-- Adds a new line (and an implicit flush)
```

Answer (score 2):

this can help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] A = { 13, 3, 4, 6, 8, 5, 10, 11 };

for (int i : A) {
        if (isEven(i)) {
            System.out.println(i + " is even");
        } else {
            System.out.println(i + " is odd");
        }
    }
}

static boolean isEven(int number) {
    if ((number % 2) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: why would you create a function for a 1-liner? `return (number % 2) == 0;`

Comment: for readable and understanding of code, you can the method isEven replace with as example method isPrime